# Mirror Android Tablet to VGA monitor via Cable- NO DiSPLAY

Tags: hdmi, screen-mirroring

Specs:  Samsung Monitor S222B300B,
        Samsung GalaxyTab 2 (micro usb slot),
        Monitor cable,
        Male micro usb to Female HDMI w/usb power slot,
        Male HDMI to Female VGA port

notes: all connections has been connected, power was switched on the monitor, power on the male micro usb to female hdmi cable was plugged, monitor tested with laptop to display screen and working fine

problem: monitor does not mirror tablet's screen which should easily be detected but it does not.

question: i bought the 2 sets of conectoon cables thinking there might be a defect 2nd one - same thing. does my monitor have a problem or does all monitors works for this kind of set up? is there anyhting that i should have done to make it work?

hoping for someone's help. getting me crazy. iwanted to watch on a bigger screen dont like wireless options for the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a computer hooked up to that monitor, and can hook up your phone via USB to the computer, I recommend Vysor. It's available as a chrome or windows app. Works great for screen mirroring, and the free version only uses USB

Note that there is a pro version of it, but basic functionality is free. You may also need USB debugging and ADB working